# how to install a module from my hard drive

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have another python problem that I am struggling with. I went through online tutorials and documentation but I cannot make it work.

I made a module and I would like to import it in one of my scripts. That's it! 
Online I could find several guides and tutorials about distributing your modules and installing them. This is not what I want. What I want is to have My module on my computer and normally import it inside my scripts as any other python modules.

I tried:

```
pip install --user my_package
```

I also tried putting the module in different folders inside the python27 directory and then doing import (I get error that the package does not exist).
I tried a combination of the two (putting the package in different folders and running pip.)

I know this may be a silly question but so far I found tons and tons of information and none of them could answer my question in a specific way.

Thank you in advance for all the help guys

edit: This is the content of my package

```
my_package/
  bin/
  docs/
  my_package/
    __init.py  
    my_scrip.py
  tests/
  setup.py
```

Comment: You **do** want to install it! Installing a module/package means precisely making something available to your system so that it can be launched/imported without specifying the fullpath etc. Probably the simplest way to install your module is writing a simple `setup.py` file using distutils.

Comment: did you check this page http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/packaging/ maybe it helps

Comment: Are we definitely talking about a module here, i.e., a single .py file, or do you have a package composed of several files? BTW, it's not a good idea to manually modify the contents of the python27 directory.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: You are right! My poor python knowledge did not include the difference between a module and a package until few minutes ago. Anyways, I still cannot install it, at least with the methods I tried so far.

Comment: The folder that contains your package _must_ be in a folder that's on the Python path. And it should not have a name that clashes with an existing package, since Python will stop searching for a package as soon as it finds one with the correct name. It'd probably help if you paste the folder structure of your package into your question (put it in a code block to preserve formatting).

Comment: I added the structure of the package. Very simple and almost empty. I am using it to learn all the stuff before I start the real coding.

Answer (score 3):

You should install local packages using an [editable install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs):

```
pip install -e /path/to/my_module
```

This will simply add the path to your `PYTHONPATH`. All changes you do to the files in the directory will be seen by all your scripts (you can continue working on the imported package, hence *editable*).

Later you can also remove it using

```
pip uninstall my_module
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a module installable using pip its going to require more work. But if you just want to be able to `import mymodule` from any Python script on your system you could add the location of your module to your Python path permanently using:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/dir/"
```

Just add this to your your `.bashrc` file if you are using a Bash shell.